# Chain multiple asynchronous function using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

In this code:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DB.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(data.Item)
    })
})
.then((data) => {
    let params = { Name: 'DEMO' }
    CWevents.putRule(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("Error", err)
        else console.log("Success")
    })
})
.then(() => {
    let params = { Rule: 'DEMO' }
    CWevents.putTargets(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("Error", err)
        else console.log("Success", data)
    })
})
```

The `DB.get` function here has a callback, but it would look awful to put multiple callbacks into each other, so I decided to use promises. I create a new promise, inside which is an asynchronous function. After it finishes running, it resolves and the first `.then` starts working, as desired. Then inside that first `.then` I have another asynchronous function that works much like the first one.

But there's no `resolve/reject` to run this time. So the third `.then` runs before the function inside second `.then` is finished. How can I make the third `.then` wait until the second one finished running? So function 1 finishes running, then function 2, then 3?

Comment: Can you add a `resolve()` and `reject()` instead of the `console.log()`s?

Comment: No, resolve is only defined for the first Promise() function. The .then's don't have a resolve() function.

Comment: To chain, ALL your asynchronous operations need to return promises.  Then you can return the promise from the `.then()` handler and they will sequence properly and errors will work properly.  Step 1, promisify all your asynchronous operations.  `util.promisify()` is your friend here.  Or, most databases these days have a built-in promise interface you can use instead of the callback interface.

Comment: Search promise chaining. You should take your DB and CWevents implementation into separate functions and make them return a promise. In this way your code would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `CWEvents.putRule` call inside a Promise. Then you can call the resolve or reject of the promise from `CWEvents.putRule`. This can be captured by a `then` or `error`

Your code should look like this

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DB.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(data.Item);
    });
})
    .then(data => { // data not needed as you are not using it in the remaining code
        let params = { Name: "DEMO" };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            CWevents.putRule(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error", err);
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("Success");
                    resolve() // resolve(data) if you want to pass the data from CWEvents.putRule
                }
            });
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        let params = { Rule: "DEMO" };
        CWevents.putTargets(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log("Error", err);
            else console.log("Success", data);
        });
    });
```

You could do the same thing in a much more readable way using `async await`

```js
async function process() {
    try {
        var data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            DB.get("params", function(err, data) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(data.Item);
            });
        }); // this will return a promise to the variable data

        var response = (function processData(data) {
            let params = { Name: "DEMO" };
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                CWevents.putRule(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error", err);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success " + data.Item);
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        })(await data);
        /* by using the await keyword , we can wait for the promise to be complete before moving on to the next step
          of execution.
        */

        /*
         * waiting on the response promise to complete
         */
        if (await response) {
            let params = { Rule: "DEMO" };
            CWevents.putTargets(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log("Error", err);
                else console.log("Success", data);
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error occured during operation " + e);
    }
}

process();
```

You can find more details about `async await` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Inside a `.then` you can create a new Promise and return it to the next `.then`, like this

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(1)}, 1000)
})
.then((message) => {
    console.log(message)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(2)}, 5000)
    })
})
.then((message) => {
    console.log(message)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(3)}, 1000)
    })
})
```

This will chain them together synchronously, so the output will be 1, 2, then 3. Without the construction it would output 1 and 3 at the same time, and then 2.